# What is ?. operator in java?

Tags: java, operators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java “?” Operator for checking null - What is it? (Not Ternary!)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4390141/java-operator-for-checking-null-what-is-it-not-ternary)
>   [Java Null-pointer-safe accessor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402132/java-null-pointer-safe-accessor)

Recently I read in one of the java forums about **?.** operator. They wrote that ?. could not make it to the java 7. Can anybody explain what exactly **?.** is?

Also, I like to know if this operator has any specific name or not like **?:** is known as **ternary operator**.

Comment: This is dealt with by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4390141/java-operator-for-checking-null-what-is-it-not-ternary.

Comment: Which again simply means down-vote this question.

Comment: @verisimilitude No, it just means close it.

Comment: I thought that it would be already present on SO. I searched with **?. operator** as keyword . Then why didn't SO show me these questions in search results?

Comment: Because searching for `?.` probably doesn't resgister in the search engine.

Answer (score 1):

It's called the [Null-safe operator](http://metoojava.wordpress.com/2010/11/15/java-7-awesome-features/).

Answer (score 1):

I believe you mean the Null-safe operator, [explained here](http://blog.joda.org/2009/01/java-7-null-default-and-null-safe_7527.html). It was under consideration for Java 7, but subsequently dropped.

The other common use for the `?` in Java is the ternary operator, which has been in Java since the dark ages and is explained [here](http://www.devdaily.com/java/edu/pj/pj010018).

The two are completely different features however, the only common element is that they use the `?` in some way.