# .? operator theoretically possible in java?

Tags: java, operators, isnull

I know Java doesn't support operator overloading, but it seems there are a few operators in other languages that could potentially benefit Java.

Probably my favorite example is the `.?` operator.  Members of an object are only accessed using `.?` if the object is non-null:

```
public void example(String arg)
{
    if(arg != null && arg.equals("quit"))
        ...
}
```

Could be shortened to

```
public void example(String arg)
{
    if(arg.?equals("quit"))
        ...
}
```

The `.?` operator is (at least imho) easy to read, and eliminates some extra code that can sometimes be a detriment to code readability.  In some code, there may be multiple checks on the null-state of an object or parameter, and may lead to unnecessary and excessive indentation on entire blocks of code.

Obviously, this would be no revolutionary change, but `.?` could be universally applied to all subclasses of `Object` as far as I can see.  Am I wrong?  And would this go against the logic used to decide that Java won't support operator overloading if it were to be adopted now?

Comment: No, there's definitely no way this could be integrated into Java as-is.  However, several languages that compile to Java or Java bytecode have things like this.

Comment: The so-called Elvis operator has been proposed for Project Coin: http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/coin-dev/2009-March/000047.html I'm not sure if it will be actually included the 2nd part of the Coin features that will appear in Java 8 though.

Comment: The problem is when you try to write the "else" clause... What is the cause of branching to the else? equals() returns false or arg is null? It's typically a wrong "good idea"

Comment: But you can write this if("quit".equals(arg)) cause equals does the null check. But I asume you like suport more operations and methodchaining.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `?.`? Also, if `arg` is `null`, then `arg?.equals("quit")` will be `null`, but `if` expects a boolean.

Comment: Unfortunately Java is quite verbose and conciseness is far from being its forte. And I don't see such features as the one you're describing being easily integrated into it.

Comment: similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4390141/java-operator-for-checking-null-what-is-it-not-ternary