# Java two get() methods after each other

Tags: java

I am trying to compare two int values with a method.

I have put two get methods after each other because the array[i] is a list of person objects and gethouse only gives the house object, the houseid is in another class.

I'm wondering if I can set up two get() methods after each other?

```
public Person findperson( int houseId ){

    for ( int i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ){
        if ( array[ i ].gethouse().gethouseID() == houseId  ){
            return array[ i ];
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: why not just try it?

Comment: Does the `House` class implement `getHouseId()`? If so, you're fine.

Comment: You can but you are risking a NPE

Comment: Yes, that's called method chaining. Just make sure that `getHouse()` doesn't return null.

Comment: It would be better if you add your whole class(es) with your question.

Comment: You even do a 3 "gets"- the first one is to get the i object in the array

Comment: Thanks all. Just needed to know if linking get methods togheter was possible, thats why I did not post classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this.

However I don't think it's good practise.

1. my first concern is the potential for null pointer exceptions (NPEs). If you write `a.getB().getC().getD()`, any one of these can return null. You can't tell which returned null in the resulting stack trace (excluding the last invocation returning null, which is fine). You may wish to use the [null object pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) in this scenario.
2. my second concern is more design-oriented. You're asking A for info about what it knows, then asking that result, and so on and so forth. *Objects exist to do things for you,* so you should do just that, and let your objects work for you. Get your `Person` object to do the heavy lifting.

Comment: if i remember in java 7 you can check null pointer by doing a?.getB()?.getC()?.getD()... etc

Comment: That was rejected, I believe. http://stackoverflow.com/a/4390187/12960. But anyhow, it gives you a null. That may/may not be what you want

Answer (score 1):

If your `house` class (whatever is returned from `gethouse()` implements gethouseID(), the person instance at `array[i]` is not null, AND `gethouse()` returns something non-null, this will work fine.  Otherwise, this will bomb out with either a compilation failure, or at runtime with a null pointer exception.  You're safer to get the person, check it for null, get the house, check it for null, then get the houseID and compare to the one you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

First you get a Person object, then with calling gethouse() you get a house object and then you call gethouseID() to get the Integer.
This should absolutely be possible.