# Any recommendation on how to reduce the number of 'if' statements in this code snippet?

Tags: java

```
public void method() {
    returnValue = optional.absent();
    try {
        GetDate dateResponse = client.call();
        if (dateResponse != null) {
            myDate = dateResponse.getDate();
            if (myDate != null) {
                returnValue = convertDateToAnotherDate() //actual function
                if (!returnValue.isPresent()) {
                    LOG.error("Missing required fields");
                }
            } else {
                LOG.error("No myDate");
            }
        } else {
            LOG.error("Service returned no dateResponse");
        }
    } catch (CustomException exception) {
        LOG.error("Custom service failed");
    }

    return retVal;
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly.

Comment: There's really not much to this question, is there...just a smattering of code...and a few magic variables, too...and your log variable is inconsistent.  Does this truncated example even *compile* on your end?

Comment: Consider making `client.call` and `GetDate.getDate` throw an Exception on failure (if applicable)? I try to *avoid* null values if I can.

Comment: I think the way you're doing it is superior to most of the potential "improvements".  Sometimes `if` statements just gotta be nested.

Comment: @Lesleh That is incorrect. `?.` is not available in Java 7 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4390141/java-operator-for-checking-null-what-is-it-not-ternary

Comment: I'm tired and for a second I thought that Java 7 added the Elvis operator and somehow I never found out about it... Damn you, Lesleh, for getting my hopes up.

Comment: Oops, I guess I was thinking of Groovy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the if's, but you can rearrange to make it a lot clearer an logically organised, following principles if:

- fail early
- minimise nesting
- don't declare variables until needed/minimise their scope

After applying the above tenets:

```
public void method() {
    try {
        GetDate dateResponse = client.call();
        if (dateResponse == null) {
            LOG.error("Service returned no dateResponse");
            return optional.absent();
        }
        myDate = dateResponse.getDate();
        if (myDate == null) {
            LOG.error("No myDate");
            return optional.absent();
        }
        returnValue = convertDateToAnotherDate() //actual function
        if (returnValue.isPresent())
            return returnValue;
        LOG.error("Missing required fields");
    } catch (CustomException exception) {
        LOG.error("Custom service failed");
    }
    return optional.absent();
}
```

Notice how now the tests are all positive tests (using == rather than !=, which our tiny brains can comprehend better). The indentation (nesting) is reduced, so readability is up. The returnValue variable is only needed in the middle of the code too, so no need to declare it early.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine them, as in:

```
if(dateResponse!=null && dateResponse.getDate() !=null)
```

Comment: You would still need one more `if` for the case where `dateResponse==null && dateResponse.getDate() !=null` (or vice versa depending how you want to order the code).

Comment: How in the world would dateResponse.getDate() be not null if dateResponse was null?  You would just get a null reference exception.

Comment: and this is java so it would short circuit anyway

Comment: @Vulcronos You are totally right, I didnt read the code fully.

Comment: @Dgrin91 It happends to all of us.

Answer (score 0):

Given the way you're reacting to what could happen if those values returned `null`, perhaps it's a better idea to throw exceptions from the calling methods, and log the exception out.  You can also change your `dateResponse` to an `Optional<GetDate>`, and behave appropriately when it's absent.

Consider:

```
public Optional<Date> method() {
    Optional<Date> returnValue = Optional.absent();
    Optional<GetDate> dateResponse = client.call();

    if (dateResponse.isPresent()) {
        try {
            Date myDate = dateResponse.getDate();
            returnValue = convertDateToAnotherDate(date); //actual function
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            LOG.error(e);
        }

    } else {
        LOG.error("Service returned no dateResponse");
    }

    return returnValue;
}
```

- I'm assuming that `client` will return an `Optional<Date>`, and if it's present, we'll behave normally.
- I execute normal business logic, as if the threat of `null` isn't possible.
- If an error occurs (which I consider to be an `IllegalStateException`), I expect the methods that I call to throw it.
- I log the exception that occurs, and provide a meaningful message when the exception is constructed.

An example structure of `getDate` could read like this:

```
public Date getDate() {
    if(date == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("No date present");
    }
    return date;
 }
```

...and now we're down to one `if`.

I genuinely don't know what types your variables are (I mean, I *really* don't - I asked if this would compile and I have my doubts), so this is about as far as I can go with the suggestion.